# How to hide/show or Filter SP List drop down values based on a drop down value selection in another choice column in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom

One of the Project I am working on, I have about three site columns:

1. Program with choices: program 1, program 2, program 3.
2. Program Type with choices: debt, grant, loan, equity, balance etc.
3. Document Type with choices: test 1, test 2, test 3 and test 4.

I can not use cascading drop-down approach as I am leveraging a site template to create subsites. So in this case if the above columns were part of a list, then I will have copies of these lists on each site i create and it will be difficult to manage. So i am leveraging site columns.

The above 3 columns are added to a library on the site I am saving as template. So the business scenario vise, I would like to do this: If someone selects program 1 from Program column then in next column called Program Type, the user should only see program 1 and program 2 and program 3 should be hidden.

Next based on Program 1 selection in Program Type, the next column called Document Type should only show test 1 and test 2 as of choices and test 3, test 4 must be hidden.

I would want to achieve this using JSOM as I am working with SP Online/Office 365, basically I will just put this code on the edit form of a sharepoint library. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.